# Drupal - configure home icon button

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

In my drupal localhost, when I hover over the 'home icon' button I want the menu items to drop down as shown in the image below. What should I configure for the same?

[image]

Comment: Making sure your requirement .. you want both parent and child menus to expand on hover on home icon buton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, Drupal on provided screenshot has [Administration menu module](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu) installed.

In case you want to build you own navigation, you might want to take a look at the [Superfish module](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish).

Comment: Yes I wanted to install Adminstration module